# Куда выводятся команды print и куда вводить input в VS code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

При работе в VS code я не смог найти то место, куда выводятся print и куда вводить input. Где мне найти оператора печати?

Comment: Наберите код, сохраните его в файле, запустите код - в правом нижнем углу появиться вкладка "терминал", в ней надо вводить символы и выводиться print.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**WINtowo4ka**, в верхнем меню vscode вам надо найти и запустить Терминал

Терминал - это оператор печати

В верхнем меню вы найдёте "Файл Правка Выделение Вид Переход Выполнить **Терминал** Справка"

У меня также можно запустить терминал сочетанием горячих клавиш `CTRL+SHIFT+ё` или CTRL+SHIFT+` это три клавиши слева друг над другом